# NPM + 'DEBUG' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, npm

```
DEBUG=knex* nodemon server.js
```

leads to an error as follows:

> 'DEBUG' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable
>   program or batch file.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! nodeapp@1.0.0 start: `DEBUG=knex* nodemon server.js`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the nodeapp@1.0.0 start script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with that but a Google search revealed this. Uncertain if it is the same thing.

> The legacy debugger has been deprecated as of Node 7.7.0. Please use --inspect and Inspector instead.
>
> <sub>[source](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/#legacy-debugger)</sub>